# Given a Primary color, how to decides what will be the OnPrimary color by material design guidelines?

Tags: colors, angular-material, material-design, material-ui, materialize

In the [material color tool](https://material.io/resources/color) there is a place where you choose the primary color and it shows you the text color on primary.

Given a color in hexadecimal string, how to know what will be the suggested text color on that color?

e.g.

Some colors will suggest that the text should be black

[image]

Others will say that it should be white

[image]

**Observation**: Any language is ok, just want to know what is the logic / function to do it.

Answer (score 0):

They wrote something about [text legibility](https://material.io/design/color/text-legibility.html#text-types). Apart from that, I played around a bit. It seems like it's a weighted mean of the r,g,b parts of the color. Blue has significantly moreimpact than green, which has slightly lessimpact than red. So it is probably something like `(1*r + 0.9*g + 1.2*b) / 3.1 > 0xff` (2.85 is the sum of the weights). If it surpasses the threshold, the text is black, else it is white.

Answer (score 0):

In react's material-ui they have a ["formula"](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/styles/createPalette.js) to create it, which uses the same logic as [material components](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/blob/ac46b8863c4dab9fc22c4c662dc6bd1b65dd652f/packages/mdc-theme/_functions.scss#L54).